# How to checked looping checkbox with array

Tags: php, checkbox

I have products in my database like this:

```
  1 -> torch
  2 -> speaker
  3 -> laptop
  4 -> handphone
  5 -> mouse
  6 -> lcd
```

and in edit form, id product (example : 1,3,4,5 ) have been selected, but my form didn't selected the checkbox properly. 
here is my code :

```
$selected = array(1,3,4,5);

foreach ($selected as $val)
    $q=mysql_query("Select * from product");

while ($r=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='product[]'";
    if ($r['id'] == $val) echo "checked"; 
    echo"> $r[product]<br>";
}
```

the result is only id no 5 is selected, it should be 4 products selected,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because last iteration over query result is when $val is 5, so all other are not checked. Change the loop this way:

```
$selected=array(1,3,4,5);
$q=mysql_query("Select * from product");
while ($r=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
   $ch = in_array($r['id'],  $selected)?"checked":'';
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='product[]' $ch> {$r['product']}<br />";
}
```

BTW, don't use `mysql_` functions - they are deprecated, and will be removed in future. Switch to `mysqli` or `PDO` with prepared statements to prevent malicious code injections.